# How to dynamically show ListBoxes in two synchronized boxes

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm currently making a transferring data from one listbox to another. 
With WPF I have:

```
            <Grid>
                <ListBox Margin="10,29,194,301" Name="LeftListBox"/>
                <ListBox Margin="0,29,16,301" Name="RightListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="173" />
                <Button Name="AddButton" Height="23" Margin="34,135,227,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="AddButton_Click">Add &gt;&gt;</Button>
                <Button Name="RemoveButton" Margin="227,135,34,264" 
                Click="RemoveButton_Click">&lt;&lt; Remove</Button>
            </Grid>
```

For my C# code, I created two methods that loads the left box's elements by using an array of Strings and the right one's. 
Now My issue is that I want an element of the left box to be placed into the right box after the last element of the right box's list. So when I click on add, it should execute this method:

```
    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the right item and it's value and index
        currentItemText = LeftListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        currentItemIndex = LeftListBox.SelectedIndex;

        ObservableCollection<string> oList;
        oList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>(toRemoveList);
        RightListBox.DataContext = oList;

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        RightListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

        (RightListBox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>).Add(currentItemText);
        if (toAddList != null)
        {
            toAddList.RemoveAt(currentItemIndex);
        }

        // Refresh data binding
                   ApplyDataBinding();
    }
```

But the problem is that when I select an item from the left box, then click on add, it adds the new item into the right box but when I add a second item, it replaces the last one item that I added at the first step.

After that, the second problem is, how would be implemented the RemoveButton_Click ? Is it the same way as the previous method ?

Comment: You're defining a new `Binding` object when adding.

Comment: so the better is to define it at the constructor right ?

Comment: Yep, otherwise it will be overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to do this much of code for this. Follow below given steps for more robust and maintainable approach.

1. Create two `Observablecollection` corresponding to left and right `ListBox`
2. Bind `Observablecollection` to `ListBox`
3. On `Add` button click, remove the `item` from observable collection assigned to left listbox and add to the oberservable collection binded to right grid.

You need not to update the bindings explicitly. Observable collection notify the collection changes automatically.

In code -

```
public ObservableCollection<ApplicationFormats> Formats { get; set; }
```

Xaml -

```
<ListBox Name="LeftListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Formats}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Does it work with binding a List of Strings to a ListBox in this case ? I mean, do I really need to create an ObservableCollection ?

Comment: You are already using `Observable collection` in new `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>(toRemoveList)`. It should work and will have maintainable code.

Comment: I just added the line you showed me but nothing is appearing in the ListBox. the biding name I chose is the name of the `ObservableCollection` but still I don't see where the error is

Comment: I just tried what you just edited on your post but still can't find out why it just show me the hover of the element from the `ObservableCollection` but not the strings..

Comment: found out that it needed to be `            ToAddList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>(_toAddList);
            LeftListBox.ItemsSource = ToAddList;` in the constructor